# Chartjs : showLine depending on value

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a simple Chartjs line chart.

I want to draw the line if the value in dataset is higher than 10 for example and put

```
showLine: false
```

If the value doesn't match the condition.

How can I do that ? There is no information in the doc.

[Link to doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html)

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milostimotic/e8n4xd4z/)

Comment: you could set you `values < 10` to `null` in your dataset.

Comment: Yes, but if I do that it will not show the point

Comment: Could you be more specific? For values < 10 you just want to show a point and all values >= 10 should be connected by a line? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes this is right

Comment: I think then you could use two datasets in your chart. One with values higher then 10 and all others null. And a second one the other way around. The first one with showing line and the other with just dots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a Chart with two datasets. The first one is containing all points `>10` and `null` for values smaller than 10. To span the line over the gaps note the `spanGaps: true` option. The second one is exactly the opposite. Here we hide the line by adding `showLine: false`.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById ('myChart').getContext ('2d');
var chart = new Chart (ctx, {
    
    type: 'line',

    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                spanGaps: true,
                data: [12, null, 15, 20, null, 30, null],
            },
            {
                label: "My second dataset",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(135, 99, 225, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(135, 99, 225, 1)',
                showLine: false,
                data: [null, 9, null, null, 8, null, 7],
            }
        ]
    },

    options: {}
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```